# How to call an instance method by passing its name to an inherited method, with correctly-typed arguments?

Tags: javascript, typescript

We've defined a base class that will be subclassed many times. We want to define an `exec` method on the base class that accepts the name and arguments of a method on a derived class, and then calls it.

However, we've run into an issue with the typing of the arguments of the derived class's method. Here's a snippet that demonstrates the error:

```js
class BaseClass {
    exec<
        Self extends Record<MethodKey, (...args: any) => void>,
        MethodKey extends keyof Self,
        Method extends Self[MethodKey],
    >(
        this: Self,
        methodKey: MethodKey,
        ...args: Parameters<Method>
    ) {
        this[methodKey](...args);
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {   
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.exec(`sayMessage`, `Hello`); // Error: Argument of type '["Hello"]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<this["sayMessage"]>'.
    }

    sayMessage(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&target=99&ts=5.3.3#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)

Why doesn't this work, and how do we correctly type the `exec` method so that it accepts the other method's arguments?

Comment: Constraints are not used as inference sites (see [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234)) so there is no place from which `Method` can be inferred when you call `exec()`. You should only make generic type parameters which are explicitly mentioned in the call signature.  For example, you could refactor to use just args and key as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZ5K9N).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I didn't know about `NoInfer` or `PropertyKey`! Very cool!

Comment: So shall I write up an answer?

Comment: I'll do it when I get a chance, might not be for a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is actually that the type inferred for `Self` is the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), which is an implicitly [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the current class instance type. And since [the `Parameters` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), it means that `args` is of type `Parameters<this["sayMessage"]>`, a *generic conditional type*. The compiler has no idea what values might or might not be assignable to such a type because it tends to just *defer* evaluation.  Until it knows exactly what `this` is, it doesn't hazard a guess as to what `Parameters<this["sayMessage"]>` might be.  And so it fails.

It's much easier on the compiler if you give it values of the exact type it's supposed to infer. So instead of `args` being some complicated thing, have it be its own generic type parameter `A`, and try to rewrite other things in terms of it.  For example:

```
class BaseClass {
    exec<
        A extends any[],
        K extends PropertyKey
    >(
        this: Record<K, (...args: NoInfer<A>) => void>,
        methodKey: K,
        ...args: A
    ) {
        this[methodKey](...args);
    }
}
```

This is very similar to yours, except now we only have two generic type parameters. There's `A`, constrained to a list type, and `K`, corresponding to your `MethodKey`, constrained to `PropertyKey` which is just a utility type equivalent to "keylike" types, `string | number | symbol`.

And then for the [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) we say that it is of type `Record<K, (...args: NoInfer<A>) => void>`.  This is essentially just "something with a property of key `K` which is a function accepting an arg list of type `A`" except we don't really want the compiler to try to infer `A` from `this`. It doesn't work out. So we use the new [`NoInfer` utility type introduced in TypeScript 5.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-4/#the-noinfer-utility-type) to tell the compiler not to try. (There are workarounds for 5.3 and below, but I'm not worried about them).

And now when you call it, it works. The compiler is happy to see that `this` is of a type like `{sayMessage: (...args: string)=>void}`, and it doesn't need to try to deal with generic conditional types at all:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.exec(`sayMessage`, "hello"); // okay
    }

    sayMessage(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.4.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4CgCQCAeCwAPDtgILT4AuCAdgCYxi0CeA2gLoA0pA0pXhoMYABQBOAewAOCMVRa8ELHAD4AFKSoALAJYQAXNABKhCWPpFeXaGoB09sGIDmB6ADkJASVoAzWUTIVAEpoAF4VaAA3CR16FR5sbABbBG0JekUWQytSe1tHF0MyHBCsRO09NhS0jKUOOwdnCCCAbhwAX0xOzFBIGABZFhQ+gSFGOERhtDLgCVoIKjEAV2AqMzVS0gglmTENtvLdCFt8QjUAAwgwFn6EKDAnBHPrACItBBAQCRfWjswcK43O5XR5qFL3R6GBZiHS0JybRKzeYSEAIWxfJxg4EPBC-bCddpAA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand why, but it works when Args is defined prior to the method:

```js
class BaseClass {
    exec<
        Args extends Array<unknown>,
        Self extends Record<MethodKey, (...args: Args) => void>,
        MethodKey extends keyof Self,
    >(
        this: Self,
        methodKey: MethodKey,
        ...args: Args
    ) {
        this[methodKey](...args);
    }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.exec(`sayMessage`, 32);
    }

    sayMessage(message: number) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&target=99&ts=5.3.3#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4rQN4CgCQCAeCwAPDtgIIBOA5jPgC4IB2AJjJRWAJ5ECujA1owD2Ad0YA+ADSkAyghAAzaPSatoAJUJCKzIgFkEdABZDmAaQSdJ0ABQA6B2GoQAXNEo0AlNAC846ABuQgCWzFKkBsamFpzKeAwsMPyWQkpyitLY4jakxsGu0OkKmdgAtoYm5pZukZUxJQ52TjRuHhA43ljY2HkQANrlUVWcALr2js6eANw4AL6Y85igkDB6nCgrcQlq8BDIqDBdwEKMEHQUPMB02jadpBA8AA4IFLcz3b12+IQ2AAYQXAMUDAVAQv2sAGYAEzTOaYHAAzhAgGgmzlYGgtyMHilABGLzu3WOpyEIAQdhAQioaIQGIQsOw81mQA)

Credit to this chat in the Typescript discord: https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1215722676904132648/1215722676904132648